# Short date style input mask txt showing as plain string in MS Access 2013

Tags: date, ms-access, delimiter, input-mask, datasheet

I have an text entry control with the input mask 00/00/0000. However it comes into the data table as just a string of numbers, e.g. 05132015. I have the datatype in the schema set to short text with a format of mm/dd/yyyy. Actually, I don't understand the difference between the format (set in the table design mode) and the input mask. Just my ignorance. I don't have a short date data type in the drop down list. In short, I want to have the user enter a short date in the format mm/dd/yyyy and have it show up in the datasheet view with the slashes.

Edit:
I'm having the same problem with running times with an input mask 00:00:00.

Edit:
I found out that I can specify shortened versions of the DateTime datatype. That will do the trick. However, in the short term, is there a way to use an input mask and still have the delimiter come through?